# PHP Encryption: AES-128-CBC with 256 bit key?

Tags: php, php-openssl

I am new to encryption and having some difficulty learning it, I would like to know what would happen if you used a **256bit** key but **AES-128-CBC** as the encryption method?

I tried it and I know it works but I don't understand how or why? Does it change to AES-256? or does the key get truncated or does the length of the key not matter?

Answer (score 1):

Key and encryption method are entirely two different things. No it does not change the encryption method if you change the key size.

Use PHP's "openssl_encrypt" function to encrypt using AES-256 (or any other method).

Here is very basic example of PHP AES-256 Encryption.

```
$text = 'Hey. Please Encrypt me';
$key = 'yHHEaF3Ht41wfcypJ2U5GES82Rpzl6yD';
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

$my_encrypted_string = openssl_encrypt($text, 'aes256', $key, iv);
```

Comment: I want to use AES-128 however the key is 32 bytes, does that matter?

Comment: You can use 32 Byte key for AES-128. However it is always better to use advanced encryption mechanisms such as AES-256.